# SonarQube DB lacking values

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

I connected my sonarqube server to my postgres db however when I view the the "metrics" table, it lacks the actual value of the metric.

Those are all the columns I get, which are not particularly helpful. How can I get the actual values of the metrics?

My end goal is to obtain metrics such as duplicate code, function size, complexity etc. on my projects. I understand I could also use the REST api to do this however another application I am using will need a db to extract data from.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know connecting to db just helps to store data, not to display data.

You can check stored data on sonarqube's gui

- Click on project
- Click on Activity